# How to ask the user to enter input in c++ in my class's and objects

Tags: c++, class, object

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date {
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;

public:
    void setDay(int day) {
        if(day>=1 && day<=31)
        Day = day;
    }
    int getDay() {
        return Day;
    }
    void setMonth(int month) {
        if(month <= 12)
        Month = month;
    }
    int getMonth() {
        return Month;
    }
    void setYear(int year) {
        if(year >=1111)
        Year = year;
    }
    int getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    void DisplayDate()
    {
        cout << "Days:  " << Day << " \n";
        cout << "Month: " << Month << " \n";
        cout << "Year: " << Year << " \n";
    }
    Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        Day = day;
        Month = month;
        Year = year;
    }
    void Birthday()
        {
            cout << "Your Birthday is " << Day << " / " << Month << " / " << Year << "\n";
        }
    

};

int main()
{
    
    Date date1 = Date(10, 10, 2000);
    date1.DisplayDate();
    date1.Birthday();

}
```

This code is for entry of the date year and month. How do I add the cin function to ask the user to enter his data?
I have tried adding `cin` in my main function, but it provides me with lots of errors.

Comment: What exaclty have you tried? What errors did you get? Technically it should be as simple as writing `cin >> nameOfTheVariable`.

Comment: You can write a setter function to do that. A separate function that performs all those cin operations and then assigns those values to literals.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a constructor which gets the data you need from any `std::istream` object like `std::cin`.

Simply add the constructor to your class:

```
class Date {
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;

public:

    Date( std::istream& is )
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter day" << std::endl;
        is >> Day;
        std::cout << "Please enter Month" << std::endl;
        is >> Month;
        std::cout << "Please enter Year" << std::endl;
        is >> Year;
    }   
... REST OF YOUR CLASS ...
};
int main()
{

    //Date date1 = Date(10, 10, 2000);

    // Construct your object with the constructor and the `std::cin` object
    Date date1{ std::cin };
    date1.DisplayDate();
    date1.Birthday();

}
```

Now you can also constrcut your class from a file or any other `std::istream`. If you like o also read from files, it makes no sense to output to `std::cout` for the requested parms :-)

Comment: what's the purpose of  "std::istream& is" in the Date in the public

Comment: `is` is a reference to any kind of `std::istream`. So you can pass `std::cin` also as a file eg. std::ifstream.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what problem it is you are having, could you list the errors you are getting? You should be able to just write `int day; cin >> day;`.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you did something like
`cin >> date1.Day >> date2.Month >> date3.Year`
, which obviously won't work since your variables are private. Make them public or enter them in other variables and set their values by using a method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot understand what your issue is. You just need to add the `cin` object to ask the user to enter their data, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int day=0, month=0, year=0;
    cout << "plearse enter day month year" << endl;
    cin >> day >> month >> year;
    Date date1 = Date(day, month, year);
    date1.DisplayDate();
    date1.Birthday();

}
```

Comment: Tried using this method but i keep receiving syntax errors due to multiples initialization.

Comment: Maybe it is because of version of complier, try to initalize variables,```int day = 0,month = 0, year = 0;```

Comment: Just a quick clarification, `cin` is not a function it is an object provided by the standard library. See the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: you are right, cin is an object, because my english is poor, so expressed it ambiguously,  :-)